# How to change message when save model in django?

Tags: django

When save model on browser. django will showing message "The ...... was added successfully.".I tried to change message at get_queryset() it look like too complicate. I want to know the best way how to change this message? and Where is to change?

[image]

[image]

How i can to change message?

Comment: Share your view. `get_queryset` is definitely *not* the place to add messages.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I add image done. The best way how i can to change this message?

Comment: please do *not* include images of code, but code itself: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode